# Take number from date

Tags: php, date

Here is my php function for taking First day & last day of a month.

```
$start = strtotime($fromDate);
$first_second = date('Y-m-01', $start);
$last_second  = date('Y-m-t', $start);
```

My question is How can i take the day number form the date.For eg:If date is 28th february I want to get output as 28 only.

Comment: `$last_date = date('t', $start);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$fromDate=date('Y-m-d');
$date_array=getdate(strtotime($fromDate));
print_r($date_array);
```

The output will be

```
   Array
(
    [seconds] => 0
    [minutes] => 0
    [hours] => 0
    [mday] => 8
    [wday] => 5
    [mon] => 2
    [year] => 2019
    [yday] => 38
    [weekday] => Friday
    [month] => February
    [0] => 1549584000
)
```

Take value from array as per your requirement.